# Is it possible to produce identically-behaving binary extension fields using different irreducible polynomials?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, trace

Let $GF(2^m)$ be a binary extension field with constructing polynomial $f(z)$ be an irreducible, primitive polynomial over $GF(2)$.

Is there any possibility that two (or more) different $f(z)$ can produce **exactly** the same field (not simply isomorphic) for calculations with its polynomials as elements?

For example, for $GF(2^{233})$ is there any case that e.g. the following irreducible constructing polynomials $f_1(z): z^{233} + z^{74} + 1$ and $f_2(z): z^{233}+z^{159}+1$ to produce identical field traces for **all** elements $\in GF(2^{233})$?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are two distinct irreducible primitive polynomials, then none of them is a multiple of the other one in $GF(2^m)[z]$. But the $0$ element of the field $GF(2^m)[z]/\langle f(z)\rangle$ is the set of all multiples of $f(z)$ and the $0$ element of the field $GF(2^m)[z]/\langle g(z)\rangle$ is the set of all multiples of $g(z)$. These are distinct sets. So, $g(z)$ does not belong to the first set, whereas $f(z)$ does not belong to the second one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I come from an engineering background and although I understand most parts, can you please elaborate a bit on your comment about the $0$ element in $GF(2^m)$? Given my Trace example, Trace can be either $1$ or $0$ and (through brute force algorithms) we have found cases where subsets of elements constructed by different $f(z)$s present identical Trace outputs when solving equation $x^2+x=w$ in $GF(2^{128})$. If indeed there is no way for this to be true, then maybe our case has to do with specific characteristics of the underlying subset of elements $\in GF(2^{128})$?

Comment: I did not mention the $0$ element of $GL(2^m)$ in my answer. What I did mention were the $0$ elements of the quotients $GL(2^m)[z]/\langle f(z)\rangle$ and $GL(2^m)[z]/\langle g(z)\rangle$, which are subsets of $GL(2^m)[z]$. More precisely, they are the sets of all multiples of $f(z)$ and of $g(z)$ respectively. So, the $0$ element of $GL(2^m)[z]/\langle f(z)\rangle$ is not the $0$ element of $GL(2^m)[z]/\langle g(z)\rangle$.

Comment: Ok sorry I missed the notation for the quotient ring.